# Open with dialog appears after choosing a file on Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-10.0, filechooser

After upgrading my phone(Redmi 7a pie) to android 10 sometimes open with dialog appears when choosing a file with file chooser

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,null), 1);
}`
```

I have also tried with "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT"

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks
[image]

Edit: A solution from @Rinkal Patel with "ACTION_PICK"
[image]
Very limited

Comment: I am not clear , would you please clear me . Do you want to add implicit intent receiver functionality to your app ? But its not listed your App on Android 10 "Open with" dialog?

Comment: @Zahid Islam,If you mean onActivityResult function,yes i have that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,null), 1);
}
```